# Edit SASS variable from angular 2 typescript

Tags: typescript, sass, angular, ionic2

I wish to get color from the user and modify the existing sass color variable to the color choose by the user. I saw a [link](https://github.com/vigetlabs/sass-json-vars), but still there is no example related to angular 2 on this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[`SASS`](http://sass-lang.com/guide) is `CSS` pre-processor, so by the time you're client `HTML` markup is consuming it, the variables have already been materialized and now form standard `CSS`.

> Once you start tinkering with Sass, it will take your preprocessed Sass file and save it as a normal CSS file that you can use in your web site.

As *[Manu Valdés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37412022/2410379)* calls attention to, there are other things that you can do with **Angular2** specifically to help with styling. For details on component styling check out the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html).

Comment: I have two application in a single repository and i wished to change the scss variable of one application from other as per users choice.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into [theming](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/theming-your-app/).

Comment: Well. I want to change the colors in the theming itself so that the variable is used in the entire application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline styles like `<div [style.color]="colorVar">` so you can change the `colorVar` value from ts to change the `color` of the `div`

Comment: I have used the sass variable in many locations and i wish all to get updated as per the user's choice.

Comment: don't use the sass variable, use the typescript variable.

Comment: you mean to use the typescript variable as global and use it across the app?

Comment: If you need it globally, you can put the variable in a service provider that you inject on your pages, so that you can access the variable it from every template; this way when you change the value it will update in your templates globally.